# How to update a counter variable when reading a file in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, counter

I am working on a distance calculator that's supposed to read a file from a text that contains several rows with various levels of distance. I am then supposed to compare the first distance to the second one, get the difference and then store the difference in a new variable, then that new variable compares itself with the next row, etc. This comparison is supposed to happen through the entire text file until the For-loop finishes. Here's some of the code I've written:

```
file_name = input("\nEnter name of data file: ")
text_file = open(file_name,'r')
for line in text_file:
    line = line.strip()
    rows = line.split(" ")
    latitude = float(rows[0])
    longitude = float(rows[1])
    longitude_two = longitude
    latitude_two = latitude
    distance = float(calculate_distance(latitude,longitude,latitude_two,longitude_two))
    print(distance)
```

The text file is really basic and looks something like this:

```
54.24525 -66.25451
66.24544 -52.32658
88.21414 -52.99985
85.32111 -49.32323
```

every time I run this loop, my output is all zeros. If anyone could help me that would be fantastic!

Comment: Neither `lat`, `long`, `latitude_2`, or `longitude_2` are being updated in that for loop.

Comment: Further, print the `line` - make sure you're actually reading what you think you're reading ;)

Comment: you need to read the file: 
    for line in read(text_file):

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I went ahead and fixed it :)

Comment: You should show what calculate_distance function is.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you calculating the distance between two pair of points that happen to be the same?

Comment: @joanne72205 Please be sure to Accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi @joanne72205, you can update this question with the extension from the other question you had. Make sure you also post the output and errors of you program to reveive better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many have pointed out in the comments, this bit of code is killing you.

```
latitude = float(rows[0])
longitude = float(rows[1])
longitude_two = longitude
latitude_two = latitude
```

Try somethinbg like this.

```
file_name = input("\nEnter name of data file: ")
text_file = open(file_name,'r')
latitude = None
longitude = None

for line in text_file:
   line = line.strip()
   rows = line.split(" ")
   latitude_two = float(rows[0])
   longitude_two = float(rows[1])
   if latitude != None:
       distance = float(calculate_distance(latitude,longitude,latitude_two,longitude_two))
       print(distance)

   longitude = longitude_two
   latitude = latitude_two
```

Comment: Wow that totally fixed everything! I had a feeling I needed an if statement but I wasn't sure what to put in it! Thank you so much!

Comment: you should simply use `if latitude:`

Comment: Correct @Alexander but just added the null comparision on the on the off chance that some point might be on the equator.

Comment: `if latitude or longitude:`?

Comment: I Always mix up the two. The Greenwitch mean line then

Comment: That's like winning ten PowerBalls in a row!